# Playing a song after a song has finished Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I am working on a app port for android but have run into a problem that I have spent roughly 8 hours trying to fix. I have these 2 songs

```
    Ptero_Lose_Music
    score
```

that are loaded in through a variable with

```
    "Ptero_Lose_Music" : "audio/Ptero_Lose_Music"
    "score"          : "audio/score"
```

When I call these two songs in my gameover screen, I want to play the lose music first then the score. I call them like this

```
    Ptero.audio.play('Ptero_Lose_Music');
    Ptero.audio.play('score');
```

which plays them both at the same time. So far I have tried

```
    Ptero.audio.play('Ptero_Lose_Music').addEventListener('ended', function(){
         Ptero.audio.play('score');)}
```

and more numerous if statements dealing with time. I have tried using .currentTime of the gameover scene as a parameter for an 'if' statement to    mediate the time in between songs but it still plays them at the same time. I believe I do not understand how to properly sort these class audio's.

So I updated the snippet with your answer and seems to freeze before entering the gameover screen or playing the audio

```
function init() {
    Ptero.audio.addEventListener('ended', function _next() { // named so..
        //this.removeEventListener('ended', _next); // .. we can stop infinite loop
        this.play('score');
    });
    Ptero.audio.play('Ptero_Lose_Music');
    //Ptero.audio.play('drop_menu');
```

I am not necessarily trying to use an eventlistener, I just want the best way to play one sound after one has finished.

Comment: https://github.com/shaunlebron/pterodactylattack is the repository I am working from. The file this code is in is called scene_gameover.js in the project/src/ folders.

Comment: Still have been unable to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using audacity and just combined the 2 sounds into one and then just initialized at the lose screen with

```
    Ptero.audio.play('Ptero_Lose_Music');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you've used the event listener, you've tried to chain it on [`mediaElement.play`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods) which is a *void* method. Instead, set up the listener then play it after

Assuming `Ptero.audio` is the `<audio>` *element*

```
Ptero.audio.addEventListener('ended', function _next() { // named so..
    // this.removeEventListener('ended', _next); // .. we can stop infinite loop
    // replace _src_ or <source>?
    this.play('score');
});
// set up _src_ or <source>?
Ptero.audio.play('Ptero_Lose_Music');
```

---

Also, you haven't shown exactly what you're doing in your code as `mediaElement.play` doesn't expect any arguments, this is why I've added the comments `// set up _src_ or <source>?`

Comment: It doesn't seem to like some syntax or function, it freezes right before it gets to the gameover scene with this snippet in there, but thanks for respoding.

Comment: I am not sure of what code should be in place of your commented code. I believe thats where my problem lies is that i dont know what source has to do or _src_.